# Angular Bootstrap directive not working in ng-repeat

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

Based on a jsfiddle I made a directive, which shows some information in a Bootstrap Popover, when hovering over a Bootstrap badge or clicking into it. It's working fine, as long it's "standalone"

[I made a plunker to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLrxHdb8pzcfyGa9n8Bc?p=preview)

```
(need to add code here)
```

The button and the first to badges in the wells are doing fine.

The badges with dynamically generated ids in the ng-repeat are not doing anything at all.
With the badges with fixed ids, only the first one works (as this is initialized 2 times), which makes sense.

What I do not understand is, in the console log you can see, all the badges in the ng-repeat are found and set up.

Don't know, where to look anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: I used it, but exactly this scenario was not possible with it. It works same (without jquery) as long you do not want to use other options as the defaults. So I steped back to the standard bootstrap.

Comment: Is this the functionality that you want at this plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/jpRh0fJfiFnsOavpW55s?p=preview  , if not, then what is it that you want to work differently than what the angular-ui library provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you try to rely on the angular-ui bootstrap library to accomplish the functionality that you want.  But based on your reliance on using the `id` attribute and your desire to use dynamically generated ids I figured that your problem was in the way that you get the element with the popover attribute.  You don't need to do a `$("#" + elemId)` to get the element for the popover, you already have a reference to the element as one of the parameters in your link function.

Right now you have:

```
testApp.directive "popoverClickNHover", ->
  restrict: "A"
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    asPopover = undefined
    console.log "popoverClickNHover"
    asPopover = (elemId) ->
      clickToggle = undefined
      enterShow = undefined
      exitHide = undefined
      popoverTriggerElem = undefined
      console.log "asPopover: " + elemId
      popoverTriggerElem = $("#" + elemId)
      console.log popoverTriggerElem
      popoverTriggerElem.data "state", "hover"
      ...
      return

    asPopover attrs["id"]
```

But you can just use the `element` that  the `link` function gives you and it will work:

```
testApp.directive "popoverClickNHover", ->
  restrict: "A"
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    asPopover = undefined
    console.log "popoverClickNHover"
    asPopover = () ->
      clickToggle = undefined
      enterShow = undefined
      exitHide = undefined
      popoverTriggerElem = element /* just use the element, no need to do $("#"+elemId) */
      console.log popoverTriggerElem
      popoverTriggerElem.data "state", "hover"
      ...
      return

    asPopover
```

Here's an example using the element from the link function: http://plnkr.co/edit/jA6zc0JQKiQaoQNo7BaH?p=preview

And here's a different example using angular-ui/bootstrap:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jpRh0fJfiFnsOavpW55s?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Jose. Sometimes you do not see the forest because of all the trees. Finaly everything shrinked down to stop event propagation on the popover in the directive, to achieve what I needed. That part was not covered in the plunker, but your comment did lead me in the right direction.